# Regular expression to match certain subdomains

Tags: regex, preg-match

I need to match with **preg_match** the urls of a certain domain that end on .co but not match those who end on .com

example:

```
www.cool.com
www.cool.com.co [MATCH]
www.cool.co [MATCH]
```

I was trying to use the expression `[\.co]{3}` but it matches me all the URLs (www`.co`ol`.co`m`.co`)

Thanks in advance for the help ;-)

**[EDIT]**

URLs like `www.cool.co/coolness` should also be a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it!

The regexp was: `/\b\.(co)\b/g`

```
www.cool.com
cool.com
www.cool.com.co [MATCH]
cool.com.co [MATCH]

www.cool.com/coolness
cool.com/coolness
www.cool.com.co/coolness [MATCH]
cool.com.co/coolness [MATCH]
```

Comment: bear in mind that your stated solution will match `cool.co.microsoft.com`, `cool.com/blah.php?x=d.co` or even `uncool.net/b.co.h.p.php/3/4` as well... - not sure if you were aware of this

Comment: @CodeJockey yeah, but right now it fits my needs. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex

```
/((.*)(.co))$/gm
```

See this **[DEMO](http://regexr.com?31956)**

### EDIT:

```
/((.*)(.co)($|/)(.*))/gm
```

See this **[DEMO 2](http://regexr.com?3195c)**

Comment: nice! but it seems to skip something like cool.com.co/coolness